# How many types of heading does an HTML contain?

Tags: html, tags

The HTML contains six types of headings which are defined with the  to  tags. Each type of heading tag displays different text size from another. So,  is the largest heading tag and  is the smallest one.

Answer (score 2):

```
     Larger Text  
     Smaller then H1 Tag 
     Smaller then H2 Tag 
     Smaller then H3 Tag 
     Smaller then H4 Tag  
     Smallest Text
```

H1 is the Largest head tag and H6 is smallest head tag

`<h1> Larger Text </h1>` 
`<h2> Smaller then H1 Tag </h2>`
`<h3> Smaller then H2 Tag </h3>`
`<h4> Smaller then H3 Tag </h4>`
`<h5> Smaller then H4 Tag </h5>` 
`<h6> Smallest Text </h6>`

Answer (score 1):

There are Six types of Html Tags h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6

Usage:

```html
<h1>This is heading 1</h1>
<h2>This is heading 2</h2>
<h3>This is heading 3</h3>
<h4>This is heading 4</h4>
<h5>This is heading 5</h5>
<h6>This is heading 6</h6>
```